# Mailman 3 Hyperkitty indexes not being built

Tags: whoosh, mailman

My config looks like this:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.whoosh_backend.WhooshEngine',
        'PATH': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "fulltext_index"),
...
```

I have whoosh 2.7.4 installed. But my `fulltext_index` directory contains only one file, `_MAIN_0.toc`, which hasn't been updated in two years.

What could be going on here? Presumably Hyperkitty should be indexing new messages as they are archived. I could run update_index to fix the index now but then it would just go out of date again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyperkitty updates the index via periodic jobs. You should add the following to e.g. `/etc/cron.d/mailman`:

```
@hourly  mailman  /opt/mailman/venv/bin/mailman-web runjobs hourly
@daily   mailman  /opt/mailman/venv/bin/mailman-web runjobs daily
@weekly  mailman  /opt/mailman/venv/bin/mailman-web runjobs weekly
@monthly mailman  /opt/mailman/venv/bin/mailman-web runjobs monthly
@yearly  mailman  /opt/mailman/venv/bin/mailman-web runjobs yearly
* * * * *  mailman  /opt/mailman/venv/bin/mailman-web runjobs minutely
2,17,32,47 * * * * mailman  /opt/mailman/venv/bin/mailman-web runjobs quarter_hourly
```

This snippet is taken from page
https://docs.mailman3.org/en/latest/config-web.html#scheduled-tasks-required

You can also check an example project in the Hyperkitty repo that contains the following [crontab example](https://gitlab.com/mailman/hyperkitty/-/blob/master/example_project/crontab):

```
# This goes in /etc/cron.d/.
# Replace "apache" by your webserver user ("www-data" on Debian systems) and
# set the path to the Django project directory

@hourly  apache  django-admin runjobs hourly  --pythonpath /path/to/project --settings settings
@daily   apache  django-admin runjobs daily   --pythonpath /path/to/project --settings settings
@weekly  apache  django-admin runjobs weekly  --pythonpath /path/to/project --settings settings
@monthly apache  django-admin runjobs monthly --pythonpath /path/to/project --settings settings
@yearly  apache  django-admin runjobs yearly  --pythonpath /path/to/project --settings settings

# Currently Hyperkitty has no minutely and quarter_hourly jobs.  The purpose of
# the next lines is to ease the upgrading process, in the eventual case that
# Hyperkitty will utilize minutely or quarter_hourly jobs.
2,17,32,47 * * * * apache  django-admin runjobs quarter_hourly --pythonpath /path/to/project --settings settings
* * * * *  apache  django-admin runjobs minutely  --pythonpath /path/to/project --settings settings
```